# Personal gain from a post?

Tags: discussion

I would like to "advertise" a personal (Jewish) project of mine. First of all I would like help editing, and second I would like people to know about the project. I hesitate to do this because it feels like it breaks the rules of the forum.

How might I do this advertising in an appropriate way, or should I just refrain from doing so altogether?

By the way, I have no monetary incentive since the project is under a CC licence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your user profile**
Feel free to promote any projects you like in [your user profile](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile). (Though it looks like you, [wolf_math](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/14676/wolf-math?tab=profile), have already.)

**Q&A posts**
I recommend that you read the Help Center post on ["How not to be a spammer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)." It indicates that it's fine to make references to your project, within reason, in Q&A posts that you write, as long as you disclose your self-interest there. The most important aspect, in my opinion, is to make sure that the Q&A posts stand on their own as worthwhile and fitting, and that the references to your project are genuinely relevant.

**Mi Yodeya chatroom**
There's nothing wrong with promoting your project, especially if it's Judaism-related, in our main chat room, [V'dibarta Bam](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam). Of course, do keep it within reason.

**Community promotion ads**
You may post a proposed ad for your project as an answer to the current [Community Promotion Ads](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads) post. (See there for requirements.) If the community expresses sufficient support for it (by voting it up to +6), it will automatically go into the rotation of ads that run on the sidebar of the front page.